# Can you block a function in an iframe from outside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to use an `iframe` which loads its source from a different website like such:

`<iframe src="http://...> </iframe>` in between the `<body> </body>` tags of an `html` file.

The source of the `iframe` is a html file that contains some `javascript` and a table, with the former being responsible for populating the table. The `javascript` however also contains a function that is triggered by an `onclick` action.

I would like to use the `iframe` as is, but wrap it in something that prevents the specific function contained in the source of the `iframe` from being executed (the function opens a different website).

Is this at all possible, and if yes, in which direction should I take my investigation to discover a solution?

Comment: Another domain = **NO**

Comment: Sounds like a security nightmare waiting to happen :\

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sandbox attribute in the iframe.

```
<iframe sandbox="" src="http://...."> </iframe>
```

It will apply all restrictions in your iframe, but you can allow some thing like:

**allow-same-origin**:  Allows the iframe content to be treated as being from the same origin as the containing document

**allow-top-navigation**:
Allows the iframe content to navigate (load) content from the containing document

**allow-forms**: Allows form submission

**allow-scripts**:
Allows script execution

More info on [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

Comment: I tried several sensible combinations, but I could not achieve the desired result. Using the sandbox property I can block the unwanted function, but since sandbox obviously isn't selective and given that there are several functions that I need to be working (the ones populating the table), which are also being blocked by the sandbox property, this does not solve my problem.

The idea was good though!

Comment: Ok. I will be waiting for a better solution too.